# ASP.net: How to handle non-valid model with foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a model with Foreign keys:

```
public class Route : IDbEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Flight number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Flight number is required")]
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Aircraft")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Aircraft is required")]
    public int? AircraftId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AircraftId")]
    public virtual Aircraft Aircraft { get; set; }
}
```

On call of `Show` view or `Edit` view i use this for retrieve an object:

```
public new async Task<Route> Get(int id)
{
    return await Context
        .Set<Route>()
        .Where(e => e.Id == id)
        .Include(e => e.Aircraft)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

And it works great.

But if `Edit` method received non-valid model, i try to return model to `View`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(TEntity e)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(e);

    var isSuccessfull = await service.Update(e);

    if (!isSuccessfull) return StatusCode(500);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`Edit` method receives model but with null references to foreign keys.

And this method returns model to view, but references to foreign key object is null and view can't render this object correct.

So, why Edit method receive model with null references? And how to return non-valid model with correct references to view?

Answer (score 1):

On postback, the ViewModel will only contain properties for which you did render an `<input>` in the HTML.

There are two possibilities to solve this:

- post all properties that are needed to render the view. Then the ViewModel will always contain these values and they are also available in the error case.
- reload the data from the DB and merge it with the posted model in the error case.

I prefer the first method. Lets assume you need the id and name of the aircraft to render the view, but they are not editable in this view. Then in your `Edit.cshtml`, render a hidden field to roundtrip these properties:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Aircraft.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Aircraft.Name) // property of related object
```

PS: Because you use the entity model to render the view, the aircraft would also be updated if you choose the first approach. You can prevent this by using a ViewModel to render, and only map the properties that can actually be edited to the entity in the POST Edit action.

Comment: What do you think about $.get() query with retrieving data into the page elements without set any values inside model? I just send GET request each time when edit page loaded and it works great. Data - is a primary key. It looks great, i think. But what did you think about this?

Comment: If I understand your approach correctly, this would be similar to the second possibility: merge the posted data with fresh data from the DB. You just do it trough AJAX instead of in the controller. Just make sure that you keep the posted data (i.e. the new values of the editable properties) in the error case, or the user looses the inputs he has just made.

Comment: I send Id of FK entity from model to some action of controller and handle returned data:  $.get('@Url.Action("GetAircraft", "Aircrafts")', { id: "@Model.AircraftId" }, function (data, params) {
  $('#aircraftId').select2({ data: JSON.parse(data) });
 });

Comment: Yes. Lets also assume you have an `<input>` where the user can edit the flight number. If an error occurs during postback (e.g. the entered flight number is not valid according to your validation rules because of a typo), you would return the flightnumber as you have received it and a validation message. This is what happens when this line is executed: `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(e);` In this case, you should not overwrite the flight number that the user entered with the data you receive through $.get(), or the user input would be lost.